# Is there a closed form for $\int \frac{e^{a \sqrt{(x-b)^2+c^2}}}{\sqrt{(x-b)^2+c^2}}dx$

Tags: integration

I am seeking a solution for the integral

$$ \int \frac{e^{a \sqrt{(x-b)^2+c^2}}}{\sqrt{(x-b)^2+c^2}}dx$$

if possible.

Comment: With $c^2 t^2  = (x - b)^2  + c^2$ you can reduce it to $$
\int {\frac{{\mathrm{e}^{act} }}{{\sqrt {t^2  - 1} }}\mathrm{d} t} .
$$

Comment: O.K., and where to go then? Integration by parts will not help after that. Does $$ \int{\frac{e^{At}}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}}dt $$ have a closed form ? Or is it a well-known formula?

Comment: There is no closed-form for the anti-derivative of $\frac{e^{At}}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$.  One could enforce the substitution $t=\cosh(y)$ and transform to $\int e^{A\cosh(y)}\,dy$.

Comment: @MarkViola . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ x = b + \sqrt{u^2 - c^2}$ to obtain
$$ I = \int \frac{e^{a \, \sqrt{(x-b)^2 + c^2}}}{\sqrt{(x-b)^2 + c^2}} \, dx = 2 \, \int e^{a u} \, (u^2 - c^2)^{-1/2} \, du. $$
By expanding the exponential this becomes:
\begin{align}
I &= 2 \, \int e^{a u} \, (u^2 - c^2)^{-1/2} \, du \\
&= 2 \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} \, \int u^{n} \, (u^2 - c^2)^{-1/2} \, du \\
&= - \frac{2 \, u \, \sqrt{u^2 - c^2}}{c^2} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a u)^n}{(n+1)!} \, {}_{2}F_{1}\left(1, \, \frac{n+2}{2}; \, \frac{n+3}{2}, \, \frac{u^2}{c^2} \right).
\end{align}
In terms of the original variables this result becomes
$$ I = - \frac{2}{c^2} \, (x-b) \, \sqrt{(x-b)^2 + c^2} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a \, \sqrt{(x-b)^2 + c^2})^n}{(n+1)!} \, {}_{2}F_{1}\left(1, \, \frac{n+2}{2}; \, \frac{n+3}{2}, \, \frac{(x-b)^2 + c^2}{c^2} \right) $$
which is valid for $c \neq 0$. If $c = 0$ the integral is given by
$$ I = \int \frac{e^{a \, (x-b)}}{x-b} \, dx = \text{Ei}(a \, (x-b))$$
where $\text{Ei}(x)$ is the exponential integral.

Answer (score 1):

*Not a closed form but (I hope) better than nothing.*

What you could try for
$$I=\int{\frac{e^{At}}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}}\,dt$$ is a series expansion
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \,\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} \,t^{-(2 n+1)}$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \,\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} \,A^{2n}\,\Gamma (-2 n,-A t)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the series expansion for $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}$$ valid for all $t$?